# Excel Conditional Formatting- Early or late vs specific date in the workbook- always showing early

Tags: excel, formatting

I have to make cells on my file turn green if it is early/ontime and red if late. When i formatted the cells as below, they always turn green, no matter if it is early or late. I'm wondering what is wrong with my formatting. The only difference i see that should have been made between the two is the change of the sign in between the index match functions.

This also worked when I set it up for when the cell reads N/a to format the cell as white. So i do not believe it is the order of the conditional formatting or the stop if true function.

```
On Time
="INDEX(Raw!$AA:$AA,MATCH($A:$A,Raw!$C:$C,0))">"INDEX($M:$M,MATCH($A:$A,Raw!$C:$C,0))"

=due date > actual date

late
INDEX(Raw!$AA:$AA,MATCH($A:$A,Raw!$C:$C,0))"<"INDEX($M:$M,MATCH($A:$A,Raw!$C:$C,0))

=due date < actual date
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you really want but if you just want to turn the cells green if cell = early or ontime and red if cell = late you just need to go to to the Conditional Formatting tab create a new rule > select "Format only cells that contain" > at the bottom of the window select "Specific text" and write the text you want > finally click on "format" and choose the options you want.

[image]

Comment: my plan is to input a date into cell1 and compare that to date in cell 2 on the Raw tab on my workbook.  I want it to turn green if cell 1 is before cell 2 and red if after cell 2.

Comment: can you please look at this again?

Comment: can you please review with my comment